# Oracle JDBC (ojdbc) writes invalid doubles to oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I are experiencing a strange problem writing a certain double value to an Oracle database via the OJDBC drivers.

If I write the exact double value **7.00E+20** into a field of type FLOAT(n), BINARY_FLOAT, BINARY_DOUBLE or NUMBER(38,10) by OJDBC, the value cannot be retrieved in Oracle tools like SQL Plus or SQL Developer. However, similar values such as 7.00E+19, 7,000001E+20 and 7.00E+21 do not cause any problems.

The special value can be retrieved with another JDBC call, or if I use fake arithmetics like `SELECT (strange_field + 1 – 1) FROM mytable` in SQL Plus.
If I try to read `strange_field` directly, the value is displayed as nothing or (null) in SQL Plus and SQL Developer.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(id VARCHAR(20), strange_field FLOAT(126));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, strange_field) VALUES ('Value by SQL Plus', 7.00E+20);
```

Sample groovy script which shows the effect (the issue occurs also in Java or applications like SQuirreL SQL):

```
import groovy.sql.*

println "Start SqlTest.groovy"

// Oracle
driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe"
username = "test"
password = "test"

id = 'Value by OJDBC'
double value = 7.00E+20 //error!
//float value = 7.00E+20 //value is stored correctly!

sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)
try {
 sql.execute 'INSERT INTO my_table (id, strange_field) VALUES (?, ?)', id, value
 sql.eachRow('SELECT id, strange_field FROM my_table'){row -> println row}
} finally {
  sql.close()
}

println "Finished SqlTest.groovy"
```

[image]

SQL Plus:
[image]

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE strange_field IS NULL` don't returns the affected row.

If `strange_field` is of type BINARY_FLOAT or BINARY_DOUBLE, the value 7E+20 is displayed as `NaN` in SQL Plus and cannot be retrieved again by JDBC or the arithmetic trick in SQL Plus.

I have already tested with ojdbc7 and ojdbc10 drivers, different JDKs (8 and 17), and Oracle databases (12.2, 18c and 21c). The issue occurs in every constellation.

I also suspect that the error might occur with other float values.

Has anyone already experienced a similar problem, can reproduce it and/or has a idea for a workaround?

Comment: What is the output of `DUMP(strange_field)` for the affected row?

Comment: I'd say it is known bug in Oracle's JDBC drivers. There is some Java property which will instruct JDBXC drivers to use different algorithm to encode doubles.

Comment: I can only say that from my experience with financial software were the numbers really do matter - we are using only BigDecimal in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example using SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DatabaseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // System.out.println(200000000000000000000d);
        // System.out.println(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        // System.out.println(200000000000000000000d < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        // System.out.println(200000000000000000000d < Double.MAX_VALUE);
        // System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("DatabaseTest url user password");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        
        String url = args[0];
        String user = args[1];
        String password = args[2];

        testFLOAT(url, user, password);

        System.out.println();

        testFLOATSetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary(url, user, password);
    }

    private static void testFLOAT(String url, String user, String password) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("--FLOAT datatype test");

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("user", user);
        p.setProperty("password", password);

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, p)) {
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                try {
                    stmt.execute("DROP TABLE test1");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                }
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE test1 (step NUMBER(10), num FLOAT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, remark VARCHAR2(100))");
            }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test1 (step, num, remark) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 1);
                stmt.setFloat(2, 200000000000000000000f);
                stmt.setString(3, "setFloat(_, 200000000000000000000f");
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                stmt.setInt(1, 2);
                stmt.setDouble(2, 200000000000000000000d);
                stmt.setString(3, "setDouble(_, 200000000000000000000f");
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                stmt.setInt(1, 3);
                stmt.setBigDecimal(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(2, -20));
                stmt.setString(3, "setBigDecimal(_, 200000000000000000000)");
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT num, DUMP(num, 16), remark FROM test1 ORDER BY step")) {
                stmt.execute();
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(3) + " : " + rs.getBigDecimal(1) + " dump: " + rs.getString(2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void testFLOATSetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary(String url, String user, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("--FLOAT datatype test with SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary=true");

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("user", user);
        p.setProperty("password", password);
        p.setProperty("SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary", "true");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, p)) {
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                try {
                    stmt.execute("DROP TABLE test2");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                }
                stmt.execute(
                        "CREATE TABLE test2 (step NUMBER(10), num FLOAT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, remark VARCHAR2(100))");
            }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test2 (step, num, remark) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 1);
                stmt.setFloat(2,  200000000000000000000f);
                stmt.setString(3, "setFloat(_, 200000000000000000000f");
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                stmt.setInt(1, 2);
                stmt.setDouble(2, 200000000000000000000d);
                stmt.setString(3, "setDouble(_, 200000000000000000000f");
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                stmt.setInt(1, 3);
                stmt.setBigDecimal(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(2, -20));
                stmt.setString(3, "setBigDecimal(_, 200000000000000000000)");
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT num, DUMP(num, 16), remark FROM test2 ORDER BY step")) {
                stmt.execute();
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(3) + " : " + rs.getBigDecimal(1) + " dump: " + rs.getString(2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover malformed numbers stored by JDBC driver can not be transferred using expdp/impdp.

Upon import impdp gives following output:

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
ORA-02374: conversion error loading table "USER"."TEST1"
ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-02372: data for row: NUM : ''


ORA-02374: conversion error loading table "USER"."TEST1"
ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-02372: data for row: NUM : ''
```

Summary. Avoid using setFloat and setDouble in you code(even with other databases). Anyways Oracle internally stores numberical types in form of digits - like BigDecimal does. Convert your number into BidDecimal format on your side and pass these digits to database driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the issue with the data pump. With the property `"SetFloatAndDoubleUseBinary"`, the value was correctly written to oracle database. Thanks ibre5041!

But is the issue a known bug of ojdbc?

Comment: It's not a bug. It is known behavior that doesn't always do what you expect. What is happening is that is Oracle Database JDBC `setFloat` and `setDouble` send numeric values to the Oracle Database as Oracle SQL `NUMBER` type, not `BINARY_FLOAT` or `BINARY_DOUBLE`. The flag described by @ibre5041 tells the driver to transport `floats` and `doubles` as `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE`. Another more targeted way to accomplish the same thing is to use `OraclePreparedStatement.setBinaryFloat` and `OraclePreparedStatement.setBinaryDouble`. These methods send the values as binary types not `NUMBER`